# Multi page support in Firepad or other editor

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, multipage, firepad

I'm working on creating an in-browser document editor.

One of the requirements is to visually split long document into multiple A4 pages (on screen). Exactly the same way as MS Word or Google docs do.

Came across Firepad and I cannot find anywhere in documentation if it supports this feature.

Can someone confirm or alternatively point me to a good rich-text-editor that does support this feature.

Thank you very much.